# Meaning of "$\exists$" in "$\{y \in Y : \exists x \in X \text{ such that }f(x) = y\}$"

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic, quantifiers

I came across this definition of the range of a function:

> For a function $f : X → Y$, the range of $f$ is $$\{y \in Y : \exists x \in X  \text{ such that }f(x) = y\},$$ i.e., the set of $y$-values such that $y = f (x)$ for some $x \in X.$

I have a little doubt regarding the use of “$\exists x \in X$”. Shouldn't it be  “$\forall x \in X$” instead, since the range of a function is the set of all values that $y$ can acquire, which is by mapping all $x$'s in $X$ to $Y?$

Comment: You might, in the future, find slightly different uses of this word, the range of $f:X\to Y$ could also be defined as all of $Y$, and the set you wrote is then the image of $f$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> > For a function $f : X → Y$, the range of $f$ is $$\{y \in Y : \exists x \in X  \text{ such that }f(x) = y\},$$ i.e., the set of $y$-values such that $y = f (x)$ for some $x \in X.$

Th given set is more accurately read “the set of elements of $Y$ such that each, for some element $x$ of $X,$ equals $f(x)$” or, more simply, “the set of elements of $Y$ such that ***each*** equals *some* output of $f$”.

> I have a little doubt regarding the use of “$\exists x \in X$”. Shouldn't it be  “$\forall x \in X$” instead

On the other hand, your suggested set $$\{y \in Y : \forall x \in X,\;\,  f(x) = y\}$$ is read “the set of elements of $Y$ such that ***each*** equals *every* output of $f$”.

---

Here's a different example providing a similar contrast:

1. $$A=\{n\in\mathbb Z: \exists a\in\mathbb Z\;\,n=2a\}\\
      =\text{the set of integers such that each one is double }\textit{some }\text{ integer}\\
      =\{\ldots,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,\ldots\}\\
      =2\mathbb Z.$$

   Set $A$ is populated precisely with the even integers:

   - take some (any) integer, then double it; the result is a member of set $A$;
   - repeat infinitely.
2. $$B=\{n \in\mathbb Z: \forall a\in\mathbb Z\;\,n=2a\}\\
      =\text{the set of integers such that each one is double }\textit{every }\text{ integer}\\
      =\emptyset.$$

   Since no integer is *simultaneously* twice of $-5,$ twice of $0,$
   twice of $71,$ etc., the set $B$ has no member.

Comment: I was putting too much belief in the 'language'(which isn't precise) of the statement and not the mathematical notation(which is always precise). Thanks @ryang ! I was confused about how to read a set, which was very trivial.

Comment: @Prakhar 1. To be fair, the natural-language description of the set *can* be made precise, as shown.  2. Describing a set (translating logical and set symbols into natural language) is not always trivial, and your confusion was very understandable.

Answer (score 3):

The last line of your writing is very true, but that doesn't mean it's okay to write $\forall$.

Let me explain the reason with one very simple and specific example.

Let $f:\{0,1\}\to\mathbb R$ as $f(x)=x$. Then $\{y \mid \forall x \in \{0,1\}$ such that $f(x) = y\}$ is $\emptyset$, because $y$ cannot be 1 at the same time as 0.

Comment: I don't understand how the set you defined is ∅?! How does $\forall$ implies that y is simultaneously 0 and 1??

Comment: No, never. @Prakhar. $\{y \in Y : \exists x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y\}$ is $\mathrm{Im}f$(range of $f$), but $\{y \in Y : \forall x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y\}$ is generally $\emptyset$.

Comment: i'm unable to grasp this. But thanks @Nightflight

Comment: The set $\{y∈Y: f(x)=y \ ∀x∈X\}$ is the set of elements of $Y$ that ALL of $X$ maps to. This would only be non-empty if f was a constant map. i.e. mapping all elements to a single element of Y.

Comment: What @Lev said. That set is empty unless $f$ is constant, in which case it's a singleton containing the constant value. There can't be more than one $y\in Y$ such that $\forall x\in X, f(x) = y$ (unless $X$ is empty!)