# Can we write the definition of image of set as below?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

In my book the definition is as follows :

$f(A)=\{y \in F / \exists x \in A$
s.t. $y=f(x)\}$

Can I write it like this :
$f(A)=\{y \in F / \forall x \in E$
, $y=f(x)\}$
?

**Note: $A$ is a subset of $E$ ; $E$ is the domain and $F$ is the co-domain**.

Comment: If $f(x) = y$ for all $x\in E$, what can you say about $f$? Also, your definition of $f(A)$ has nothing to do with $A$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of "$\exists$" in "$\{y \in Y : \exists x \in X \text{ such that }f(x) = y\}$"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4288362/meaning-of-exists-in-y-in-y-exists-x-in-x-text-such-that-fx)

Comment: Your definition of an image already doesn't make sense from the beginning. Is $f$ a function $f:A\to F$ or $f:E\to F$?

Comment: SeraPhim : the second option

Comment: Fair enough, then it should be $f(E) = \mbox{ etc etc}$.

Comment: Ok just seen your edit that $A\subset E$, in that case you should write that $x\in A$ in the definition rather than $x\in E$, and keep the $f(A) = \mbox{ etc}$.

Comment: Yep my bad I've fixed it

Comment: @ryang, your link is really helpful, but I want more answers here to be sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131808/discussion-between-elie-makdissi-and-seraphim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.

Your definition would imply that for a specific $y$, $f(x)$ is always equal to $y$ no matter what value of $x$ we pick.

If you can read the definition, $f(A)=\{y\in F \;|\; \exists x \in E, y = f(x)\}$, left-to-right the order in which you say things is the order in which you choose your variables.

So, in this case we first pick some $y\in F$ and we assert that there must exist at least one value of $x \in E$ such that $y=f(x)$. If we change $\exists$ with $\forall$ it changes the definition, and we would need $y=f(x)$ to be true $\forall x$.

Comment: So when we say "y", do we mean y as in specific, I mean like "for each y"?

Comment: Which "y" do you mean? It depends if you say "$\forall y$" or "$\exists y$". If you mean the $y \in F$, that simply denotes the elements of your set